# Virtual call from base in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I'm having a problem making a a virtual call when using virtual inheritance.

Below is sample compilable code that demonstrates a code which works when there is no virtual inheritance used, and also code which will fail on runtime when virtual inheritance is used.

**BASE CLASSES**
Here are base calsses for both cases:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() { }
    virtual ~Base() { }

    // we need to make this bad call a good one!
    virtual void bad_call(void* ptr)
    {
        Base* pThis = static_cast<Base*>(ptr);
        pThis->f();
    }

protected:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
    int x = 0;
};

class Midle1 :
    virtual public Base
{
public:
    Midle1() { }
    ~Midle1() override { }
};

class Midle2 :
    virtual public Base
{
public:
    Midle2() { }
    ~Midle2() override { }
};
```

**CASE 1 GOOD**
Here is a case which makes no use of virtual inheritance (just normal inheritance), where both `bad_call` and `good_call` virtual functions work:

```
class GoodDerived :
    public Base
{
public:
    GoodDerived()
    {
    }
    ~GoodDerived() override
    {
    }
    void good_call(void* ptr)
    {
        GoodDerived* pThis = static_cast<GoodDerived*>(ptr);
        pThis->f();
    }

    void f() override
    {
        ++x;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GoodDerived good_derived;
    good_derived.good_call(&good_derived);  // OK, will print 1
    good_derived.bad_call(&good_derived);   // OK, will print 2

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**CASE 2 BAD**
And here is a case which will make use of virtual inheritance, the `good_call` function will succeed, but `bad_call` one will fail with "access violation reading location"

```
class BadDerived :
    public Midle1,
    public Midle2
{
public:
    BadDerived() { }
    ~BadDerived() override { }
    void good_call(void* ptr)
    {
        BadDerived* pThis = static_cast<BadDerived*>(ptr);
        pThis->f();
    }

    void f() override
    {
        ++x;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BadDerived bad_derived;
    bad_derived.good_call(&bad_derived); // OK, will print 1
    bad_derived.bad_call(&bad_derived); // ERROR: causes access violation

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**QUESTION**
This second case is a simple code that demonstrated the issue I'm having right now in my project, and I need assistance on how to solve this, why is virtual inheritance causing troubles?

Why first case works just fine but second one does not?

Comment: You convert `BadDerived*` to `void*` and then `void*` to `Base*`. This is undefined behaviour. You can only convert back to the **SAME** type.

Comment: @n.m. I do the same thing in case 1 and it works, what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is multiple inheritance.  If you look at a pointer cast to one base vs. a pointer cast to the other base, you'll see that they're different addresses.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok, I understand, what can I do to make this design possible? I'm receivng derived pointer as `void`.

Comment: @metablaster Just because UB does what you expect, does *not* mean that you can expect that to *always* happen. Undefined Behaviour is *undefined*, it may do *anything*, including what you expect (and anything else).

Comment: Cast it to the proper type *before* calling the function is the only thing I can think of now.  It has to be done at a point where the fully derived class declaration is available and known.

Comment: C++101. Undefined behaviour is **UNDEFINED**. A program with undefined behaviour can do **ANYTHING**. The definition of "anything" includes crashing, producing subtly incorrect output that goes undiscovered for years and costs your company a billion dollars, starting a nuclear war, stealing your girlfriend, and also doing what you have naïvely expected.

Comment: "what can I do to make this design possible?" Nothing.

Comment: @n.m. you forgot [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: Nnnnnoooo! Not the Nasal Demons! They're worse than the Bore Worms!

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you're casting a pointer to `void *` and then casting it to a different pointer type.  That doesn't work in general -- after casting a pointer to `void *`, the only useful thing you can do with it is cast it back to the EXACT SAME POINTER TYPE.  If you want to cast to any other pointer type (reliably) you need to first cast back to the same original type.

> I need assistance on how to solve this

Don't use `void *` here -- `void *` is a C solution that should never be used in C++.  Change your virtual `bad_call` method to take a `Base *` as an argument not a `void *`.  Then everything 'just works' and you don't need any of the `static_cast`s at all.  If you need to override `bad_call` in your `Dervied` class, it also needs to take a `Base *` argument, so you'll need to use `dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptr)` there to get back the original `Derived *`, but that's not a big deal -- that's precisely what dynamic_cast exists for.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over `bad_call` function in this example, it's a CALLBACK function from Windows API, and I have to deal with `void` and virtual inheritance. I think using type_traits to conditionally compile the type might work. but  problem with template base class is that it can't be used as virtual base since it will result in unrelated multiple base classes.

Comment: if its a CALLBACK, its not a virtual function, its a function pointer using a C API and there's no C++ or inheritance involved at all.  In the case where you want to call a C++ virtual function from a C CALLBACK that has a `void *` argument, then you need to make sure you cast back to the exact same type you cast from (to get the void *) before then casting to any other type.

Comment: thank you and everyone else for suggestions,I'll leave the thread unanswered for now.

Answer (score 1):

Make your call:

```
bad_derived.bad_call(static_cast<Base*>(&bad_derived));
```

You want to point to the Base part of the object but when using virtual inheritance there is no guarantee about where that will be located.

Comment: Isn't the `Base` ambiguous in OP's case thus this won't compile?

Comment: It would be ambiguous if Base were not inherited virtually but since it is there is only one Base to convert to. It doesn't matter which inheritance path is taken it results in the same address.

Comment: There are actually multiple instances of the base sub-object, therefore the address of the base class is ambiguous. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tgzzNk)

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this, step by step.

1. `&bad_derived`: A pointer to `BadDerived` with pointer value pointing to an object with type `BadDervived`.
2. `bad_derived.bad_call(&bad_derived)`: Implicitly converts `&bad_derived` to a pointer to `void*` with pointer value pointing to an object with type `BadDervived`.
3. `Base* pThis = static_cast<Base*>(ptr);`: Cast from a `void*` to `Base*`. Note that `ptr` has pointer value pointing to an object with type `BadDervived`, but `BadDerived` is not pointer-interconvertable with `Base`, thus `pThis` has type `Base*` but has pointer value pointing to an object with type `BadDervived`.
4. `pThis->f();`: Access the value of a `BadDerived` object using a glvalue (here a dereferenced pointer) of type `Base`, violates the strict-aliasing-rule. Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a solution that makes this design possible (with the help of other answers and comments).

All the code remains same except adding a templated static mehtod to base class which will deduce void to correct type:

Here is modified Base class with helper template static function:
added a comment about `CALLBACK` also.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { }
    virtual ~Base() { }

    // this is example CALLBACK from Window API but templated
    // The callback is registered with Windows in RegisterClassEx btw.
    template<typename DERIVED_CLASS>
    static void make_call(void* ptr)
    {
        DERIVED_CLASS* pThis = static_cast<DERIVED_CLASS*>(ptr);
        pThis->bad_call(static_cast<Base*>(pThis));
    }

    // we need to make this bad call a good one!
    virtual void bad_call(void* ptr)
    {
        Base* pThis = static_cast<Base*>(ptr);
        pThis->f();
    }

protected:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
    int x = 0;
};
```

And here is how we invoke `bad_call` problematic function:

```
int main()
{
    BadDerived bad_derived;
    bad_derived.good_call(&bad_derived); // OK, will print 1

    // HACA!!!
    bad_derived.make_call<BadDerived>(&bad_derived);    // OK will print 2

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This why I like C++ so much, everything is possible...